# Can you define instance method for sub documents in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

If I have a a Schema in Mongoose that's defined like:

```
var subSchema = new Schema({
  some: String
});

var topSchema = new Schema({
  subs: [subSchema]
});

var topModel = mongoose.model("Top", topSchema);
```

Is it possible to define an instance method for the sub document? I've tried the following(added before the model declaration), but it doesn't work:

```
subSchema.methods.someFn = function() { 
  return 'blah';
};
```

Comment: Can you expand on "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Actually, I figured out what I wanted to do doesn't work, but what I actually did worked.  What I wanted was a function that I can use on the collection of the subdocs, i.e. `topdoc.subs.someFn()` but what I actually declared is `topdoc.subs[i].someFn()`.

Comment: Ah, good to hear that worked.

Comment: @wciu If you resolved your issue, please post your solution as an answer to this question and accept it :)

Comment: Can you do `topdoc.someFn(topdoc.subs)` instead of `topdoc.subs.someFn()`?

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question.

What I originally wanted to do was to create a function that can be used on the collection of subdocs, as in:

```
topdoc.subs.someFn();
```

However, what I actually did with code in the original question was create a function for a subdoc itself, as in:

```
topdoc.subs[i].someFn();
```

This works.

As far as I can tell, creating a function for the collection of subdocs is not supported by Mongoose.

I got around this by defining a method in topSchema that would do what I want.

Comment: Two years later, I'm looking to make a subdoc instance method that updates the subdoc. Do you know if this is possible? `this.save()` does not seem to work. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998323

Comment: Subdocs can't be saved, you need to save the parent.  So this.parent().save() should work, but you will need to test it out.

Comment: I have since refactored, but now I'll try this. If it works I'll let you know and you can post it as an answer. Looks promising. Thanks!