# Instance Method for array of mongoose subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, authorization, mongoose-plugins

I have a mongoose schema like

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  friends: [String]
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var alice = new User({friends: ['bob']});
```

and I would like to attach an instance method to the `friends` array, e.g., a function `myFunction` that can be called like

```
alice.friends.myFunction(...);
```

Does mongoose provide a way to do so?

PS: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400440/can-you-define-instance-method-for-sub-documents-in-mongoose), @wciu asked if a function can be defined on the subdocuments itself (which is possible). The question here is if it is possible to define it on the array.

Comment: In this case `alice.friends` is already an array object, so it wouldn't make sense to add custom functions to it, unless you'd like to add a prototype to the Array object. What kind of logic would you like to apply within your function? My answer would vary based on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'd like to add authorization wrappers for creating, modifying and deleting array elements that take into account the permissions of the user that initiated the operation.

Comment: @andrenarchy That's probably best handled outside of your Mongoose ORM layer.