# How can I update a Mongoose subdocument in an instance method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose document with an array of subdocuments like this:

```
var RegionSchema = new Schema({
  "metadata": {
    "regionType": String,
    "name": String,
    "children": [{
      "name": String,
      "childType": String,
      "id": Schema.ObjectId
    }],
    "parent": Schema.ObjectId
  },

  "data": [DataContainer]
});
```

In the `DataContainer` schema, I want to make an instance method that can update the data inside itself.

**For clarity**, I want to be able to look up a `Region`, find a `DataContainer` inside the `data` array and call something like `dataCont.update()`, in which the `DataContainer` instance can do a `this.save()`. Is this possible?

Doing

```
this.save(function(err, saved) {
  console.log(saved)
  callback(err, saved);
});
```

inside a `DataContainer` instance method prints out `undefined`. The callback is hit though.

Answer (score 1):

If the `data` property is a subdocument you can easily use `populate` and update it:

```
Region.findOne({ _id: regionId })
  .populate('data')
  .exec(function (err, region) {
    // ...

    var data = region.data, // data container
        dataItem = data[0];

    dataItem.property = 'some value';
    dataItem.save(function (err, item) {
      //...
    });

    // or
    dataItem.update({ $set: { property: 'some value' }}, function (err, item) {
      // ...
    });

  });
```

Comment: It's actually an array of subdocuments. I want to make an instance method specifically because I have a certain way of combining two `DataContainer`s. Is it impossible to save them from instance methods? If so, I think I can rearrange my code a little bit.

Comment: What do you mean by words `combining two DataContainers`? if your schemas normally configured the istance method should work. Some examples here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: I mean I have a few fields and this instance method adds the fields of another instance to its own fields and tries to save the changes.